# Remove in memory cookie/session from WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

Our application uses a Cocoa WebView to sign into varies types of SSO infrastructure. For logging out or switching users i need to remove the cookie from WebView - for that I do the following

```
  NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray *allCookies = [cookies cookies];
        for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in allCookies) {
            NSLog(@"found a cookie %@", cookie.domain);
             [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
```

This approach only seems to work for persistent cookies, for In-memory cookies (which session goes away when the user shuts the browser down), it has no effect. I've tired deleting the WebView and recreating for logout/login but the cookie/session still exists. Currently i need to shut down the application and restart for the session to be removed which is not acceptable.

Does any one know how delete this cookie?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to delete your system caches right??

Comment: Hmm .. system cache and cookies are not the same thing, I only care about cookies.

Comment: ohk then it will store in some path of you rmachine right. So use NSFileManegr api to delete the same

Comment: The cookie is in memory and is not on the file system.